# What program to use to store my chat history online?

Tags: chat

What is the best program to store chat history online ?

I tried Dexrex, but I dont think it works correctly.

IM-History is also now history...

Anymore?

Comment: Question is not clear ? which protocol ? XMPP ?

Comment: Which chat program are you using?

Comment: A script which is uploading the history files to a FTP-Server?

Comment: have you tried meebo.com ?

Comment: Downvoted because you're unclear and vague with your question. But apparently someone thought the missing information makes this question clear enough to upvote. Go figure.

Comment: guys, please go to dexrex.com or im-history.com ...you will see that it works on ANY chat program.

Answer (score 2):

What are the features that you want ? Most clients should be able to edit the location of the local logs folder. If that works for you, then you can consider a free service such as 
[dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com) and store the files there. These would be synced online automagically.

Comment: please check out dexrex.com or im-history.com, and you will see what kind of program I'm looking for.